# Setup MediaWiki with MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mediawiki

I'm working on setting up MediaWiki but I'm having trouble connecting to the SQL Server database.

Credentials are good but I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot access the database: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I've followed along with some mentions of installing some additional DLL's to support this but I'm either not setting them up correctly or this isn't the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are using a MSSQL account or a windows account credentials, make sure your connection is set for the right one or at least set it to accepts both.